# How to Handle android background activity

Tags: android

I have activity stack in my android application.Suppose A and B.When the application starts the Activity A is visible.From this activity i call Activity B using startActivityForResult method.Now from here if i press Home button of device then activity runs in background that is OK.But when i relaunch the application by taping on activity icon a new instance of activity is start and show activity A rather showing the activity B.Please help me in this.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out if your launchMode of the Activity A is SingleTask.

Comment: please post your Android.Manifest

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling activity B using getApplication().startActivity(myIntent);

Comment: Hi nirav thanks for your reply.I just give this simple example to understand the question, infect i have 7 Activity in stack.So kindly provide any other solution if possible.

Comment: 820861, Can you pelase clear your actual scenario? Because in my application, if I am on 3rd activity and I press home button and then when i tap on application icon, it displays me 3rd activity only.

Comment: You are right nirav but i have this problem in HTC Inspire and HTC Explorer devices.If i start application from android market and press home button.After that if i press application icon and open the app it starts new instance of application in HTC devices.Works well in Samsung devices.